# Can't enable third monitor on second graphic card

Tags: 16.04, graphics, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, amd-graphics

When I enable third monitor I just get redirected to login screen.

Two monitors are on AMD graphic card and one is on integrated intel graphic card.

```
lspci | grep ' VGA '
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Tahiti PRO [Radeon HD 7950/8950 OEM / R9 280]
```

Do you have any tips how to make two graphics cards working together?